# To configure the add remote files to the patch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to create a patch in TortoiseSVN, but I can't commit the deleted files, eventually only the ones that have been added or changed are flagged. Help solve the problem. Patch do by pressing the right mouse button and selecting the create patch command.
Thank you in advance

Comment: To delete the files, have you right-clicked on files and select `TortoiseSVN`then `delete` command ? And what do you mean by "I can't commit the deleted files" ?

Comment: @LaurentH. I work in idea, deleted unnecessary classes, tortoiseSVN noticed them, but when I create a patch, they are not displayed in the changes, that's the problem I want to solve

Comment: Did you ensure the files you deleted were versioned ? Which version of TortoiseSVN are you using ? Which version of Windows ? Can you give a concrete example with file-tree ?

Comment: @LaurentH. Found the answer, the problem was in IDEA, there the plugin which deletes files and from SVN does not work. this had to be manually when create patch right-click on the file and delete it, then it worked. sorry for English :)